# how to convert decimal time to hh:mm time format in excel

Tags: excel

I have looked at all the options I can find on this forum, but I am unable to solve my problem. this may very well be because I only have basic excel skills. simple question..how do I convert a decimal time ie 9.25 into hh:mm format ie 09:25 ? I need to do this as I am using existing data that requires rounding to 15 mins + 2mins and I can only do this in hh:mm format. Many thanks

Comment: Can the decimal value ever be more than .6 e.g. 9.65? If so, how would this be handled?

Comment: Is this "clock time" or "elapsed time"? For example might your value to convert be > 24?

Comment: GVEE no it is always clock time.

Comment: Barry Houdini. this is always clock time, not elapsed time. these are clocking in card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your value is in A1...

Get the hours

```
=FLOOR(A1, 1)
```

Get the decimal portion

```
=A1 - FLOOR(A1, 1)
```

Convert this decimal to minutes (0.25->25):

```
=(A1 - FLOOR(A1, 1)) * 100
```

Bring the whole lot together:

```
=TIME(Floor(A1, 1), (A1 - FLOOR(A1, 1)) * 100, 0)
```

Result: **9:25 AM**

Comment: And if you really do want `9:25` instead of `9:15`, multiply by 100 instead of 60.

Comment: Good point @MarkRansom - answer updated to reflect original requirements (that was a slip!)

Comment: MarkRansom, I have now applied the solution to my spreadsheets and it has worked perfectly. If I may can I ask a supplementary question... having reached my hours worked in hh:mm ie 09:15hrs I need to subtract 0:30 mins IF hours worked exceeds 9:00 hrs.the std IF formula in decimal appears not to work. do I have to revert to decimal?  Thank you

Comment: @MaccaVIII `=TIME(HOUR(A1), MINUTE(A1) - 30, SECOND(A1))`

Answer (score 2):

If it's a `true` decimal time then `9.25` hours should convert to `9:15`. If that's the case you can just divide by 24, e.g. 9.25 in A1 then in B1

`=A1/24`

format B1 as [h]:mm and you'll get `9:15`

....and if you really do want `9:25` as the answer you could try this formula

`=TEXT(A1*100,"00\:00")+0`

format result cell as `[h]:mm`- that will work even for values > 24

If you want you can do your conversion and rounding in one go, e.g. to round to the nearest 15 minutes the first formula becomes:

`=MROUND(A1/24,"0:15")`

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have 9.25 in cell A1. First you need to extract the integer part (9). Let's put this in B1:

```
=FLOOR(A1)
```

Now we must get the decimal part:

```
=A1-B1
```

And convert it into the ratio-to-60, so let's have this in C1:

```
=(A1-B1)/0.6
```

This way, 0.25 becomes 0.4166... (Of course 0.30 would become 0.50).
Finally, add both values and divide by 24. In Excel, dates/times are stores as decimal numbers in which 1 = 24 hours. So let's place this in D1:

```
=(B1+C1)/24
```

The result is 0.392... And if you give that cell a time format, you will see 09:25.

So, now let's put all together in one cell:

```
=(FLOOR(A1)+(A1-FLOOR(A1))/0.6)/24
```

Don't forget to format the cell as time (custom format "hh:mm", for example).